# Printing elements and ignoring last two element in a table

Tags: python, arrays

I have a text file containing:

```
SKT:SSG:2:1
LN:FNC:1:1
NWS:ENY:2:0
```

I want to print out the elements in a table ignoring the last two elements which are the digits. Here's what I've done so far:

```
fileName = input("Enter file name:")
match = open(fileName)
table = []

for line in match:
    contents = line.strip().split(':')
    table.append(contents)

#add a loop to leave out last two digits?

print(table)
```

The output I get for a start is:

```
[['SKT','SSG','2','1'],['LN','FNC','1',1'],['NWS','ENY','2','0']]
```

The output I want:

```
[['SKT','SSG'],['LN','FNC'],['NWS','ENY']]
```

I've looked into a term known as array slicing and managed to come up with:

```
for i in range(len(table)):
    print(table[i][:-2])
```

but I do not know how to implement it into the code I've written as I'm not familiar with file reading just yet. Any help is appreciated. Regards.

Comment: Why not just change `table.append(contents)` to `table.append(contents[:-2])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the full row is needed in `table` for another usage, you can create a new list and print the new one:

```
print([row[:-2] for row in table])
```

If the full row is not required, you can add just the relevant values, as [CoryKramer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2296458/corykramer) mentioned in the question comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply modify your current code as below:

```
contents = line.strip().split(':')[:-2]
```

Keep the remaining code as it is. `Split` method returns a list, so you can do slicing on it as well.

Answer (score 0):

This code reads the file line by line. Each line is split on the ':' character to form a list and the list is appended to the `table` list to form a list of lists. Finally the each list in `table` is printed minus its last two elements.

```
fileName = input("Enter file name:")
match = open(fileName)
table = []

for line in match:
    contents = line.strip().split(':')
    table.append(contents)

print([content[:-2] for content in table])
```